# Solve multi-dimentional optimization problem using basinhopping

Tags: python, performance, scipy

I am searching for an optimization solution, which is a 8d vector representing 4 complex elements, where each element is within the complex circle with maximal radius 1.2.

The objective function is:

$$f: \left\|\mathbf{c}_{ref}-\mathbf{c}\right\|_{2}+\left|2-\|\mathbf{c}\|_{2}\right|$$

I am using the `scipy.optimize.basinhopping` module.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

class MyBounds(object):
    def __init__(self, xmax=[360, 360, 360, 360, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2], xmin=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ):
        self.xmax = np.array(xmax)
        self.xmin = np.array(xmin)

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        x    = kwargs["x_new"]
        tmax = bool(np.all(x <= self.xmax))
        tmin = bool(np.all(x >= self.xmin))
        return tmax and tmin

class MyTakeStep(object):
    def __init__(self, stepsize=45):
        self.stepsize = stepsize
    def __call__(self, x):
        s = self.stepsize
        x[0] += np.random.uniform(0, 1*s)
        x[1] += np.random.uniform(0, 2*s)
        x[2] += np.random.uniform(0, 3*s)
        x[3] += np.random.uniform(0, 4*s)
        s = 1
        x[4] += np.random.uniform(0, 1*s)
        x[5] += np.random.uniform(0, 1*s)
        x[6] += np.random.uniform(0, 1*s)
        x[7] += np.random.uniform(0, 1*s)
        return x

def f(input_list):
    polar_form = [rphi for rphi in zip(input_list[4:], input_list[:4])]
    x          = np.array([z(e[0], e[1]) for e in polar_form])
    # objective function componenets
    result  = abs(2 - np.linalg.norm(x, 2)) + np.linalg.norm(cref-x, 2)
    return result

def hopping_solver(min_f, min_x):
    minimizer_kwargs = {"method":'Nelder-Mead'}
    comb             = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    # define bounds
    mybounds   = MyBounds()
    mytakestep = MyTakeStep()
    optimal_c  = optimize.basinhopping(f, x0 = comb, niter=50000, T=45, stepsize=1, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs, take_step=None, accept_test=mybounds, callback=None, interval=5000, disp=False, niter_success=None)

    min_x, min_f = optimal_c['x'], optimal_c['fun']
    print(optimal_c)
    return min_x, min_f

min_f = 10**10
min_x = []
min_x, min_f = hopping_solver(min_f, min_x)
```

My questions relate to the step essentially: My first elements are angles in [0,360] and the others are in [0,1.2]. What is a suitable way to define a good step here to balance between precision and fast processing?

I am aware that this code does not return the global minimum.

Also here I chose the center of my solutions space as x0, is there on recommendations on how to choose the starting point?

Comment: Asking how to fix the code so that it finds the global minimum is outside the scope of Code Review, because our rules require that the code be already working correctly as intended. However, if you relax your expectations so that a non-optimal solution is acceptable, then we can review the code as is.

Comment: Well the code is functional. The issue of not finding the global minimum is related mostly to not using the proper parameters.

Comment: If you are primarily interested in the computational technique and choosing initial points, rather than open-ended suggestions to improve your code, then try the [scicomp.se] site instead.